# Creating a counter in excel that increases in value after clicking a command button

Tags: excel, function

I am busy with a project in Excel and i want to create a button that increases the value of a cell in every time i click it, can anyone help me along?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with either a Form control or an Active X control.

First you need to make sure you have access to the Developer tab. If you don't, you'll need to look into doing that. I'm not going to explain that here, that's a different question.

Create your button, and change the text to read whatever you want.
In the code for that button, place code similar to this:

```
    Cells(1, 1).Value = Cells(1,1).Value + 1
```

This refers to cell "1,1", which is basically A1.
For cell C1, you would indicate

```
    Cells(1, 3).Value = Cells(1,3).Value + 1
```

So you'll see that Cells is a function taking first the "row number" then the "column number".

Note that this syntax may fail if rows or columns are inserted above or to the left of the given cell (you didn't indicate any additional requirements for that, so I'm only using the simplest example here).

If you want the value to increase by more than 1, just change the "+ 1" to whatever you want to increase by.